# Edit a row of a table by transforming it into text boxes in the same page

Tags: php, html

I need to edit a row in an HTML table.
Here is the code of HTML table with PHP values:

```
<table cellpadding="2" border="1">
   <tr>
      <th align="center">اسم البضاعة</th>
      <th align="center">الرمز</th>
      <th align="center">النوع</th>
      <th align="center">الموزع</th>
      <th align="center">مكان التخزين</th>
      <th align="center">الكمية</th>
      <th align="center">السعر الاساسي الإفرادي</th>
      <th align="center">سعر مبيع القطعة</th>
      <th align="center">العدد المباع</th>
      <th align="center">التاريخ</th>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach($result5 as $rows)
    {
    ?>
   <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_code'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_cat'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['supplier'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_location'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['quantity'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['init_price'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['buy_price'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_sold'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_now'] ?></td>
      <td align="center">
         <form action='MY NEW PAGE HERE .PHP' method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
             <input class="imgClass_edit" type="submit" name="update_invent" value="" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
       <?php
        } 
        ?>
    </table>
```

And here is a picture showing some arbitrary information that I just added them with an edit button:

[image]

Now, what I need to do is, that when I click on the edit button of a row, to stay in the same page, **but the row that I want to edit it, will transform into text boxes so I can edit values, and then save them.**
So, anyone have an idea about it?

**EDIT**

**EDIT**

**EDIT**

I tried this where i created a new page as same as the one above, where when click on edit button, we will go to it and where we have a row that it is equal to id posted from the last page, put textboxes, else echo data normally. But now all of the rows are text boxes not only the row that I want.
Here is the code of the new page:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/global.php');
$result5 = '';

//ID from the last page that is posted as hidden:
$id = $_POST['rowid'];
try{
    $query5 = ("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY date_now DESC, id DESC");
    $stmt5 = $conn->prepare($query5);
    $count5 = $stmt5->execute();
    $result5 = $stmt5->fetchAll();


    //header("location: debts.php");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Phone Store Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../include/stat.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../include/printing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"> <a href="home.php"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></a> </div>
<center>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</center>
<div id="nav"><center>التقرير اليومي<a href="DReport.php"><div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/daily_reports_icon.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
  <center>
    التقرير الشهري<a href="Mreport.php"><div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/daily_reports_icon_month.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
<center>
   ديون<a href="debts.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/debt.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
<center>
  بضاعة<a href="invent.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/inventory.png" alt="Done" /></div></a></center>
<center>
  Login status<a href="login_status.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/login_details.png" alt="Done" /></div></a></center><br>
</div>
<center>
<div id="section2" align="center" dir="ltr">
<center>
<form class="form-style-9" action="insert.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="text" name="item_code" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="الرمز code" />
    <input type="text" name="item_name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="اسم البضاعة" />

</li>
<li>
    <select class="container" id="select_type" name="item_cat">
            <option value="بطاقات">بطاقات</option>
            <option value="هواتف">هواتف</option>
            <option value="اكسسوارات">اكسسوارات</option>          </select>
    <input type="text" name="supplier" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="الموزع" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="item_location" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="مكان التخزين" />

<input type="text" name="quantity" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="الكمية"/>
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="init_price" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="سعر القطعة الأساسي" />

<input type="text" name="buy_price" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="سعر المبيع"/>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_items" value="إضافة المعلومات" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</center>
</div>
<div id="section2" dir="ltr">
<table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th align="center">اسم البضاعة</th>
<th align="center">الرمز</th>
<th align="center">النوع</th>
<th align="center">الموزع</th>
<th align="center">مكان التخزين</th>
<th align="center">الكمية</th>
<th align="center">السعر الاساسي الإفرادي</th>
<th align="center">سعر مبيع القطعة</th>
<th align="center">العدد المباع</th>
<th align="center">التاريخ</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result5 as $rows) {

    if($rows['id'] = $id)
    {

    ?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_code'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_cat'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['supplier'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_location'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['quantity'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['init_price'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['buy_price'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"<input type="text" value="><?php echo $rows['item_sold'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['date_now'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><form action='' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_edit" type="submit" name="update_invent" value="" />
        </form></td>

        <?php } else { ?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_code'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_cat'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['supplier'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_location'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['quantity'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['init_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['buy_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_sold'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_now'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><form action='' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_edit" type="submit" name="update_invent" value="" />
        </form></td>
</tr>
<?php } } ?>
</table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have this image:

[image]

Comment: The html is not valid - you are nesting forms ~ very unlikely to work properly

Comment: yes, I removed one of the forms, and left only the edit form

Comment: add textboxes in each cell and hide them, on edit click, hide values and display textboxes (easy with jquery), then on form submit grab the new values and do an ajax request to update DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Edit all of your TD.

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="YourFieldNames" value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>" disabled ></td>
```

And move your open form take after `<tr>` tag.

And then use jQuery or JavaScript to delete input attribute disabled.

Comment: I want to stay in the same page, showing the same table, but the row where I clicked on the edit button of it, it will be transformed into textboxes so I can update values

Comment: You can load your data in disabled input . when you click on edit delete disable attribute with Jquery and whene you click to update set your query database update .

Comment: I didnt understand what you want me to do, if you can correct all my code, with explanation

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary example of how you might achieve this using standard javascript. This has only one row of static data but the principle should be enough for you to apply this to your recordset loop.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Change table cell contents to text fields</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            /* Find the buttons and bind listeners to them */
            function bindEvents(){
                var form=document.getElementById('editdata');
                var col=form.querySelectorAll('input[name="update_event"]');
                for( var n in col ) if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].onclick=evtListener
            }
            /* The function that does the main work */
            function evtListener(event){
                var el=typeof(event.target)!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;
                var parent=el.parentNode.parentNode;
                /* Get all child nodes that have the data-name attribute */
                var col=parent.querySelectorAll('td[data-name]');

                for( var n in col )if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ){
                    /* get the value in the table cell - store in a var */
                    var str=col[n].innerHTML;
                    /* Generate the new text input field */
                    var oInput=document.createElement('input');
                        oInput.setAttribute('type','text');
                        oInput.setAttribute('name',col[n].dataset.name);
                        oInput.setAttribute('value',str);

                    /* Append the text field into the tablecell */
                    col[n].innerHTML='';
                    col[n].appendChild( oInput );
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',bindEvents,false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='editdata' action='' method="post">
            <table cellpadding="2" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th align="center">اسم البضاعة</th>
                    <th align="center">الرمز</th>
                    <th align="center">النوع</th>
                    <th align="center">الموزع</th>
                    <th align="center">مكان التخزين</th>
                    <th align="center">الكمية</th>
                    <th align="center">السعر الاساسي الإفرادي</th>
                    <th align="center">سعر مبيع القطعة</th>
                    <th align="center">العدد المباع</th>
                    <th align="center">التاريخ</th>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Single row of static data for example purposes -->
                    <td align="center" data-name='item_name'>hobble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='item_code'>gobble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='item_cat'>gabble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='supplier'>rabble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='item_location'>dabble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='quantity'>babble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='init_price'>bobble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='buy_price'>bubble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='item_sold'>wobble</td>
                    <td align="center" data-name='date_now'>wibble</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="1" /><!-- edit this to be dynamic also -->
                        <input class="imgClass_edit" type="button" name="update_event" value="edit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have already did it, using PHP-HTML codes only, but thanks and I will use your code in my next project when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this plugin instead.Use the below link
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: I did it, using PHP and HTML codes only. I answered my question with the final code. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works using PHP and HTML codes, with `IF ELSE` statements:
When I click on the edit button of my first page, I will go to the next page that contain this code:

Here is an image showing the result:

[image]

```
<?php
require_once('../include/global.php');
$result5 = '';
$id = $_POST['rowid'];
try{
    $query5 = ("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY date_now DESC, id DESC");
    $stmt5 = $conn->prepare($query5);
    $count5 = $stmt5->execute();
    $result5 = $stmt5->fetchAll();


    //header("location: debts.php");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Phone Store Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../include/stat.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../include/printing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"> <a href="home.php"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></a> </div>
<center>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</center>
<div id="nav"><center>التقرير اليومي<a href="DReport.php"><div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/daily_reports_icon.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
  <center>
    التقرير الشهري<a href="Mreport.php"><div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/daily_reports_icon_month.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
<center>
   ديون<a href="debts.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/debt.png" alt="Done" /><br>
</div></a></center>
<center>
  بضاعة<a href="invent.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/inventory.png" alt="Done" /></div></a></center>
<center>
  Login status<a href="login_status.php">
    <div><img width="50" height="50" src="../images/login_details.png" alt="Done" /></div></a></center><br>
</div>
<center>
<div id="section2" align="center" dir="ltr">
<center>
<form class="form-style-9" action="insert.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="text" name="item_code" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="الرمز code" />
    <input type="text" name="item_name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="اسم البضاعة" />

</li>
<li>
    <select class="container" id="select_type" name="item_cat">
            <option value="بطاقات">بطاقات</option>
            <option value="هواتف">هواتف</option>
            <option value="اكسسوارات">اكسسوارات</option>          </select>
    <input type="text" name="supplier" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="الموزع" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="item_location" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="مكان التخزين" />

<input type="text" name="quantity" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="الكمية"/>
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="init_price" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="سعر القطعة الأساسي" />

<input type="text" name="buy_price" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="سعر المبيع"/>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_items" value="إضافة المعلومات" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</center>
</div>
<div id="section2" dir="ltr">
<table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th align="center">اسم البضاعة</th>
<th align="center">الرمز</th>
<th align="center">النوع</th>
<th align="center">الموزع</th>
<th align="center">مكان التخزين</th>
<th align="center">الكمية</th>
<th align="center">السعر الاساسي الإفرادي</th>
<th align="center">سعر مبيع القطعة</th>
<th align="center">العدد المباع</th>
<th align="center">التاريخ</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result5 as $rows) { ?>


<tr>
    <?php if($rows['id'] == $id)
    {

    ?>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_code'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_cat'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['supplier'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['item_location'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['quantity'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['init_price'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['buy_price'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"<input type="text" value="><?php echo $rows['item_sold'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['date_now'] ?>"/></td>
<td align="center"><form action='' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_edit" type="submit" name="update_invent" value="" />
        </form></td>

        <?php } else { ?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_code'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_cat'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['supplier'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_location'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['quantity'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['init_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['buy_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['item_sold'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_now'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><form action='' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_edit" type="submit" name="update_invent" value="" />
        </form></td>
</tr>
<?php } } ?>
</table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```